# Modal analysis for a (simple) nonlinear system

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

Consider the following (1 DOF) system:

$m\ddot u + ku=0$

where

$k=k_1, for: u>0$

$k=k_2, for: u≤0$

I would like to perform modal analysis for this simple case, where the displacements are solved over time using the eigenmodes of the system.

How can this be done?